# JWT pros and cons

Tags: spring, database, rest, web, jwt

I've read about JWT in past few days and i completely understood the concept behind it and power of authorization, time wise. My question is what happens with JWT authorization mechanisms when CRUD endpoints come in place? Lets say i have to delete a certain 'task' from specific user that sends me request, containing JWT token. Thing i have to do is to go to database, check if the user belongs to that task and upon doing so, delete that task from database. This leads to 2 database calls. My question is now, is JWT really that powerful when it comes to endpoints that contain CRUD operations which require verification that certain user can do specific action? Also, even if we didn't have to do that, we still have 1 database call which is CRUD action. Can someone help me clear this out?

Answer (score 0):

The most common model is to have the backend send a JWT token to the front end When the user authenticates. Then, this token is included with subsequent requests, and the server can use it to validate that the request is truly coming from the logged in user. Once this has been validated, the server can safely make the database call to perform the change or database action.

One thing you might consider is using a solution like Zetabase (https://zetabase.io). This provides the JWT token and all of the authentication mechanisms for you automatically, along with a system of constraints that allows you to perform the sort of tasks you're talking about here without using a back end at all, you can do it directly from the front end.

In other words, with Zetabase or even with Firebase, you skip that middle layer entirely. The database itself manages usernames, passwords, and authentication, and then you make calls to the database directly from the front end. This only works because those two databases allow for "constraints "that make sure only the appropriate users are allowed to perform certain actions.